# Is it possible to swap out React component definition without changing component identity (to maintain state/refs etc)? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a development tool that lets you create React components.

A user will start off with their component looking like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  var rand = useRef(Math.random());

  return <div>{rand.current}</div>;
}
```

but then might want to modify it like so:

```
function MyComponent() {
  var rand = useRef(Math.random());

  return <span>{rand.current}</span>;
}
```

The only meaningful change here was `<span>`, so ideally for me (to prevent full tree remounts for larger apps/preserve application state), that random number wouldn't change because the ref would be preserved - but React seems to detect the change in reference to the component definition when considering its identity: `MyComponent !== MyComponent (new)` and outputs a different random value.

This is similar to implementing HMR (Hot Module Reloading) myself - but constrained to just react component definitions.

Here is a working example to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/83xruyL5/1/

Is there any way of modifying this React behavior with something like a name/id/key attribute on the definition? Or perhaps a more generic JS approach of preserving/reusing a function/component reference while modifying its definition?

I assume this may not be possible, and am just going to be limited by React here, but am asking just in case it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
function Wrapper(props) {
    const [Component, setComponent] = useState(MyComponent);
    return Component(props);
}
```

Calling `setComponent(MyComponent2)` will re-render the wrapper, with the new `Component` but the same ref. The trick is to *call* `Component` as a function not to create a `<Component {...props}>` element. Of course, this will fail horribly if the old and new component use different hooks.

---

Instead of this hack,
I suggest you look into the internals of React to see how they implemented hot module reloading themselves. There is [react-refresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-refresh) to allow ["Fast Refresh"](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16604#issuecomment-528663101), provided by the React team.

Answer (score -1):

The useState set function will trigger a re-render anyway, and [by default, when a component re-renders, React re-renders all of its children recursively. In some cases, if you need to skip the re-rendering of components, useMomo could help](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#skipping-re-rendering-of-components).

Also:

**Swap component without changing sate and ref:**

```
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const randRef = useRef(Math.random());
  const [randState, setRandState] = useState(Math.random());

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setRandState(Math.random());
      }}
    >
      ref: {randRef.current} state: {randState}
    </div>
  );
};

const AComponent = ({ children }) => <div>A {children}</div>;
const BComponent = ({ children }) => <span>B {children}</span>; 

let isAComponent;    

const getComponent = () => {
  const MyComponent = isAComponent ? BComponent : AComponent;
  isAComponent = !isAComponent;
  return MyComponent;
};

function App() {
  const [MyComponent, setMyComponent] = useState(getComponent);
  const constChildren = ChildComponent();

  return (
    <div>
      {React.createElement(MyComponent, { children: constChildren })}    
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setMyComponent(getComponent);
        }}
      >
        hotswap component
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Hi Iman, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, while it does solve the problem in this static case, the user might create a tree of many components, each with many refs and states, which makes it hard to imagine how to apply this to (their code would need to somehow be transformed into an approach like this).

Comment: However it did raise the idea of implementing my own versions of useRef/useState/useEffect etc - that wasn't concerned with component identity. That's far from my first choice, but a good backup option.

Comment: No problem Max, Indeed  passing state props adds complexity and makes it harder to maintain and modify code. useMemo have some of the features that you are looking for but can be tricky. I normally use it for very few main components or large lists.

Comment: It seems to be working if children passed as a constant, I updated my answer.